# JqueryUI Sortable - Functionality to only move items within sublist (3rd pos)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to set a specific functionality using jquery sortable. I seem to be close but hitting an issue. I need the subitems to move to level 3 positions only - under the account types

http://jsfiddle.net/Davos8549/x6f0upng/1/

I only want the sub items to be able to drag - drop into other lists that has the class="hasItems"

I should still be able to move AR, VZ, BANK within its main container "Asset". But i should not be able to drop the whole thing into a sublist (which is the problem i'm having now).

```
Asset
    AR
        subitem2-1
        subitem3-15
        subitem3-25
        subitem2-2
        subitem2-3
        subitem2-4
    VZ
        subitem3-1
        subitem3-2
        subitem1-35
        subitem3-3
        subitem3-4
    Bank
        subitem1-1
        subitem1-2
        subitem3-45
        subitem1-3
        subitem1-4
Liability
    Bank5
        subitem1-15
        subitem1-25
        subitem1-45
    AR5
        subitem2-15
        subitem2-25
        subitem2-35
        subitem2-45
    VZ5
        subitem3-35
```

I believe the solution could be in this code:

```
<script>
            $(function() {
                $('ul.mainlist').sortable({
                    connectWith: 'ul.mainlist',
                    beforeStop: function(ev, ui) {
                        if ($(ui.item).hasClass('hasItems') && $(ui.placeholder).parent()[0] != this) {
                            $(this).sortable('cancel');
                        }
                    }
                });
                $('ul.sublist').sortable({
                    connectWith: 'ul.sublist'
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more specific with identifying your DOM elements you want to move:

First I've made some minor changes to your html, adding the class "group" to the `<li>` tag of the groups *Bank* and *Liability*, which makes them easier to identify.

I also added the class "connected" to the sublists, which I want to be interchangable, that as an example that you can have both, complete interchangable subitems a well as subitems, which are only sortable within their own group. This class "connected" is used in the `sortable()` function `connectWith` functionality, see [Connect Lists](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)

In case a group gets empty, you need to define a min-height to be able to move items back into that empty group.

then I changed the sortable to:

```
$(function() {
    $('li.group ul.sublist').sortable({

    });
    $('.hasItems ul.sublist').sortable({
            connectWith: ".connected"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

which now allows you to move as you requested.

check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qro9xvd5/) for details or

```js
$(function() {
    $('li.group ul.sublist').sortable({

    });
    $('.hasItems ul.sublist').sortable({
            connectWith: ".connected"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
body
{
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma, San-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
p
{
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}
ul.mainlist
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    width: 100px;
}

ul.mainlist li
{
    background: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    width:100%;
}
ul.sublist 
{
  min-height: 35px;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
              integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <p>sublists shouldn't be able to be dragged out of their normal list</p>
<ul id="list1" class='mainlist'>
                <li class="group">Asset
                    <ul class="sublist">
                        <li class="hasItems">Bank
                            <ul class="sublist connected">
                                <li>subitem1-1</li>
                                <li>subitem1-2</li>
                                <li>subitem1-3</li>
                                <li>subitem1-4</li>
                            </ul>
                        
                        </li>
                        <li class="hasItems">AR
                            <ul class="sublist connected">
                                <li>subitem2-1</li>
                                <li>subitem2-2</li>
                                <li>subitem2-3</li>
                                <li>subitem2-4</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="hasItems">VZ
                            <ul class="sublist connected">
                                <li>subitem3-1</li>
                                <li>subitem3-2</li>
                                <li>subitem3-3</li>
                                <li>subitem3-4</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                
                </li>
                
                <li class="group">Liability
                    <ul class="sublist">
                        <li class="hasItems">Bank5
                            <ul class="sublist connected">
                                <li>subitem1-15</li>
                                <li>subitem1-25</li>
                                <li>subitem1-35</li>
                                <li>subitem1-45</li>
                            </ul>
                        
                        </li>
                        <li class="hasItems">AR5
                            <ul class="sublist">
                                <li>subitem2-15</li>
                                <li>subitem2-25</li>
                                <li>subitem2-35</li>
                                <li>subitem2-45</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="hasItems">VZ5
                            <ul class="sublist">
                                <li>subitem3-15</li>
                                <li>subitem3-25</li>
                                <li>subitem3-35</li>
                                <li>subitem3-45</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                
                </li>
                
            </ul>
```

Comment: its working well - but i cant move the subitems to other category-subcat: https://jsfiddle.net/Davos8549/uep6qdhc/

Comment: I misunderstood that requirement and have updated the question, should do now all what you expect...